# Как отложить загрузку кода AMOCRM

Tags: javascript, amocrm, google-page-speed

Есть код, который внедряется на сайт, но он уменьшает показатели pagespeed от гугла.

```js
<script>!function(a,m,o,c,r,m){a[o+c]=a[o+c]||{setMeta:function(p){this.params=(this.params||[]).concat([p])}},a[o+r]=a[o+r]||function(f){a[o+r].f=(a[o+r].f||[]).concat([f])},a[o+r]({id:"1123514",hash:"637557d4ad30da9a66354e0afed7847f",locale:"ru"}),a[o+m]=a[o+m]||function(f,k){a[o+m].f=(a[o+m].f||[]).concat([[f,k]])}}(window,0,"amo_forms_","params","load","loaded");</script><script id="amoforms_script_1123514" async="async" charset="utf-8" src="https://forms.amocrm.ru/forms/assets/js/amoforms.js?1682542650"></script>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы он загружался позднее. P.S. Вставляю на сайт через шорткод.

Comment: добавить аттрибут `defer`, так `<script defer>`